# Memory handling in x64 vs x86 - C language

Tags: c, memory, x86, 64-bit, x86-64

When I run the code below using a GCC compiler on X64 computer the output of `i` is 90 but when running it on x86 its value still 2, so where is the difference in handling the memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int arr[3]={50,7,30};
  int i=2;

  arr[3]=90;     
  printf("arr[2]=%d,arr[3]=%d,i=%d", arr[2], arr[3], i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `arr[3]`. It is out of bounds.

Comment: `arr[3]=90;` writes out of the bounds of the array --> Undefined behaviour

Comment: when you compile x64, add `-O3` to the compilation line... I bet you will be surprised.

Comment: @AlexLop. which compilation line !?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array indexes in C start from 0, so the valid indexes for `arr` is 0, 1, and 2.  Using `arr[3]` is writing off the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your case manifests as different behavior on x86 and x64.  You'll probably also get different behavior if use you a different compiler or change the optimization settings.

Regarding this specific behavior, you seem to think that `i` should appear immediately after `arr` in memory so that writing to `arr[3]` actually writes to `i`.  There is no guarantee however regarding the ordering of local variables within a scope.  It's not just a x86 / x64 thing.

Don't read / write past the end of an array, and you won't see these types of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have explained, writing out of the bounds of your array is UB.

I'd like to point out some other thing you might not realize:
From your question it appears that you expect the access to **arr[3]** to overwrite your **i** variable.

Even if the compiler would allocate your local variables in the order they appear in your source code, (which is not guaranteed at all!), you would NOT overwrite **i**.

The reason for this is that usually the stack grows downwards. So if the compiler followed your sequence of allocations on the stack, **i** would get the lowest address in your code.

But in order to allow normal pointer arithmetic (which is what happens when using the [] array notation), increasing indices into arr will go *upwards* in the stack, and you will overwrite your function's activation record. Very bad.

Try this version of your code (compile with -fstack-protector-all in GCC):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void smash(void){
   int arr[3] = {50, 7, 30};
   int i = 2;

   arr[3] = 90;

   //Let's look at the addresses
   printf("&i = %p, &arr[0] = %p, , &arr[3] = %p\n", &i, &arr[0], &arr[3]);

   printf("arr[2] = %d, arr[3] = %d, i = %d\n", arr[2], arr[3], i);

   int i2 = 3;
   //Small loop limit can trigger stack protector *upon* return from smash()
   //Large loop limit will create a segfault *before* returning from smash()
   for(; i2 < 10; i2++)
      arr[i2] = 99999;

   //Just to see where we crash.
   printf("%d\n", i2);
}

int main(void)
{
   smash();
   return 0;
}
```